# $\mathrm{E}\left[u u^{\mathrm{T}}\right]=\sigma^{2} I_{n} \text { is untrue } \iff \text{heteroskedasticity?}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance, heteroscedasticity, covariance-matrix

$\mathrm{E}\left[u u^{\mathrm{T}}\right]=\sigma^{2} I_{n} \text { is untrue } \iff \text{heteroskedasticity?}$

I know heteroskedasticity $\implies \mathrm{E}\left[u u^{\mathrm{T}}\right]=\sigma^{2} I_{n} \text { is untrue }$

I have no idea whether $\sigma^2I_n \neq \mathbb{E}[uu^T] \implies \text{heteroskedasticity}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroskedasticity-consistent_standard_errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You could have serial correlation with homoskedasticity.

Comment: What is serial correlation? @GrahamBornholt

Comment: In your identity matrix, whether or not you have heteroskedasticity depends on the diagonal terms. Non-zero correlation (implying dependence) shows up as non-zero elements in the off-diagonals. Serial correlation is one form of dependence.

Comment: The answer to your original question would have been yes if you had specified the rvs were independently distributed.